# Verifying digital signature

Tags: c#, rsa, digital-signature

I'm trying to produce an Xml document behind an API, sign it, and validate the signature in a Console application. The creation of the Xml and signature appear to be working, but the signature is not validated in the client app.

In my API controller, I POST a customer, and that code creates and preserves a new RSA public/private key. That method returns the PublicKeyXml. I store the customer id and the PublicKeyXml in my client testing app. The customer id is in the appsettings.json and the PublicKeyXml is stored in a file.

When the client requests a license, the output Xml document is signed using the private key attached to that customer specified in the endpoint URI.

My API:

```
namespace License.HostedApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api")]
    public class LicenseController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<LicenseController> _logger;
        private const string customerDataFileName = @"Data\Customers.json";
        private readonly Dictionary<string, string> customerDictionary;

        public LicenseController(ILogger<LicenseController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(customerDataFileName))
            {
                Monitor.Enter(lockObject);
                string customerContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(customerDataFileName);
                Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customerContent))
                {
                    customerDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                }
                else
                {
                    customerDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(customerContent);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                customerDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            }
        }

        [HttpGet("ping")]
        public ActionResult Ping()
        {
            return Ok(true);
        }

        [HttpPost("customer")]
        public ActionResult<string> CreateCustomer([FromBody] string customerName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customerName)) { return BadRequest(); }

            Customer customer = new Customer(customerName);

            AsymmetricEncryptionService asymmetricEncryptionService = new AsymmetricEncryptionService();
            int keySizeBits = 2048;

            AsymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult = asymmetricEncryptionService.PersistNewAsymmetricKeyPair(keySizeBits);

            if (asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult.Success)
            {
                customerDictionary.Add(customer.GlobalId.ToString(), asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult.KeyContainerName);
                SaveCustomerDictionary();
                return Ok(asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult.PublicKeyXml);
            }
            else
            {
                return StatusCode(500, "Persistence of asymmetric key failed.");
            }
        }

        [HttpGet("license/{customerId}")]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(string customerId)
        {
            if (customerDictionary.ContainsKey(customerId))
            {
                CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
                cspParams.KeyContainerName = customerDictionary[customerId];

                RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
                xmlDoc.LoadXml("<license><mode>Trial</mode><features><feature>All</feature></features></license>");

                SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
                signedXml.SigningKey = rsaKey;
                Reference reference = new Reference();
                reference.Uri = string.Empty;
                XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
                reference.AddTransform(env);
                signedXml.AddReference(reference);
                signedXml.ComputeSignature();
                XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
                xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
                {
                    Async = false,
                    Indent = true
                };
                stream.Position = 0;
                var xWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings);
                xmlDoc.WriteContentTo(xWriter);
                xWriter.Flush();
                stream.Position = 0;

                return Ok(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray()));
            }
            else
            {
                return NotFound($"Customer {customerId} not found");
            }
        }

        private object lockObject = new object();
        private void SaveCustomerDictionary()
        {
            Monitor.Enter(lockObject);
            string customerJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customerDictionary, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(customerDataFileName, customerJson);
            Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
        }
    }
}
```

The persistence function looks like this:

```
public AsymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult PersistNewAsymmetricKeyPair(int keySizeBits)
{
    AsymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult = new AsymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult();
    try
    {
        CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
        string containerName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        cspParams.KeyContainerName = containerName;
        cspParams.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keySizeBits, cspParams)
        { PersistKeyInCsp = true };
        CspKeyContainerInfo keyContainerInfo = new CspKeyContainerInfo(cspParams);
        string pathToMachineLevelAsymmetricKeysFolder = Path.Combine(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData),
            @"Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys");
        asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult.KeyContainerName = keyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName;
        asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult.KeyStorageTopFolder = pathToMachineLevelAsymmetricKeysFolder;
        asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult.KeyStorageFileFullPath =
            Path.Combine(pathToMachineLevelAsymmetricKeysFolder, keyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName);
        asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult.Success = true;
        asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult.PublicKeyXml = rsaProvider.ToXmlString(false);
        asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult.PublicPrivateKeyPairXml = rsaProvider.ToXmlString(true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult.ExceptionMessage = ex.Message;
    }
    return asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult;
}
```

The testing client:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace TestClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        static IConfiguration configuration;

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile(path: "appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();

            string customerId = configuration.GetSection("CustomerId").Value;

            Console.WriteLine($"Customer ID = {customerId}");

            var response = await client.GetAsync($"https://localhost:58579/api/license/{customerId}");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("License fetched.");

                XmlDocument publicKeyDoc = new XmlDocument();
                publicKeyDoc.Load("test1_public_key.xml");

                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(content);

                RSAParameters parms = new RSAParameters();
                parms.Modulus = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(publicKeyDoc.SelectSingleNode("//RSAKeyValue/Modulus").InnerText);
                parms.Exponent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(publicKeyDoc.SelectSingleNode("//RSAKeyValue/Exponent").InnerText);

                RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                rsaKey.ImportParameters(parms);

                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(content);
                SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
                XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");
                signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

                bool isValid = signedXml.CheckSignature(rsaKey);

                if (isValid)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Doc signature is valid");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Doc signature is INVALID");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error fetching license: {await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Public RSA Key, stored with the client in a file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RSAKeyValue>
  <Modulus>xQIe438pmPoGKGkZoDkxrSaj1+DQH6g4tqZaZrTe5yXlD4BZZEWimWaQpuRarD3oOJPmS7GLLqBNWXepWubRkck3GyqyNY5Lraiarm7Jzp4tQ/0H0SPOcbDu6CBlmbET1tIXb0e461VmKupP35/2GSgsmSYEpDZkIF24wf+zt+wzOe7aEQiHQ2Y085yd7JbtkHWbmK8v+85a5RDvNJ75eLUgvmBiwi5RgHQEiIJkLR10IUAq5N/u4EcxvQgGa2rGlWTXMayeQJSvgv0cAMF6kQcTy9sc3MlGEa0qGplhB5FxLcq0uJN0QYQcxMNkYtLXVfrzFCbVDuptUptdNv278Q==</Modulus>
  <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

The program's output:

```
Customer ID = f9453533-ba8b-4f6e-8353-bd11700d68be
License fetched.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<license>
  <mode>Trial</mode>
  <features>
    <feature>All</feature>
  </features>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
        <DigestValue>iANXMen0uhmOxr20/p59uE2A6zHxuY3p0wZyJ/31N9o=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>njoZxBxWGD121IoBZ8yA3hZMa9QojRIS7sjkPicZn0QJv8lzqXIDoLExP1Iw8cuMl3DeSnohBaDz3RWZeqsV+xtwZLh5GN4vUefWp5CBsbRqWSLfCZ/bcVbKfybXWhIQf9kOE5gvczGw4AS1Tw3JLvF9EddAoDEbwQkCdD4jaJM=</SignatureValue>
  </Signature>
</license>
Doc signature is INVALID
```

I think I'm missing something simple, but I don't know what it is. Encoding, maybe?

Any help is appreciated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I did not checked every line of your code. It looks very close to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-sign-xml-documents-with-digital-signatures). I'd like to suggest to write test code (copy-pasting from the official sample) and check in one app will the signature verification work. Then you can add extra xml modification you had applied like `XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings);` and `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray())`. Just to be sure that stream writing does not affect the original xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please check below program that is written according to your original code? Of course it does not store any file on the storage and does not read from remote places because of simplifying the code to be able to run on an online compiler but I think this example will provide a guideline since the approach is similar.

The main differences include using *Convert.FromBase64String* and *being careful on UTF8-BOM character* in the created license XML since it causes error at LoadXml() method if the BOM character exists. Also, not using storage is a difference but since eventually files are read as string in the original code, this difference should not be very important.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TestClient
{
    abstract class OperationResult
    {
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }
    }

    class AsymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult : OperationResult
    {
        public string KeyContainerName { get; set; }
        public string KeyStorageFileFullPath { get; set; }
        public string KeyStorageTopFolder { get; set; }
        public string PublicKeyXml { get; set; }
        public string PublicPrivateKeyPairXml { get; set; }
    }

    class AsymmetricEncryptionService
    {
        public AsymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult PersistNewAsymmetricKeyPair(int keySizeBits)
        {
            AsymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult = new AsymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult();
            try
            {           
                RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keySizeBits);

                asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult.Success = true;
                asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult.PublicKeyXml = rsaProvider.ToXmlString(false);
                asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult.PublicPrivateKeyPairXml = rsaProvider.ToXmlString(true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult.ExceptionMessage = ex.Message;
            }

            return asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult;
        }
    }

    class Customer{
        public Customer(string Name) { this.Name = Name; this.GlobalId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); }
        public string Name { get; set; }    
        public string GlobalId { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> customerDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        //static IConfiguration configuration;

        public static bool StartProcess()
        {
            /*configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile(path: "appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();
            */
            string customerId = createCustomer("Test User").GlobalId;

            Console.WriteLine("Customer ID = " + customerId + "\n");

            XmlDocument publicKeyDoc = new XmlDocument();
            publicKeyDoc.LoadXml(customerDictionary[customerId]);

            string content = CreateAndSignXML(customerId, publicKeyDoc);
            Console.WriteLine("License fetched.");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
            Console.WriteLine(content + "\n");

            return VerifySignature(content, publicKeyDoc);
        }

        private static bool VerifySignature(string content, XmlDocument publicKeyDoc){
            RSAParameters parameters = new RSAParameters();
            parameters.Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKeyDoc.SelectSingleNode("//RSAKeyValue/Modulus").InnerText);
            parameters.Exponent = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKeyDoc.SelectSingleNode("//RSAKeyValue/Exponent").InnerText);
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            rsaKey.ImportParameters(parameters);

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(content);
            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");
            signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

            return signedXml.CheckSignature(rsaKey);
        }

        private static string CreateAndSignXML(string customerId, XmlDocument publicKeyDoc){
            Console.WriteLine("Started creating XML..");

            RSAParameters parameters = new RSAParameters();
            // Convert.FromBase64String is used instead of Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes
            parameters.Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKeyDoc.SelectSingleNode("//RSAKeyValue/Modulus").InnerText);
            parameters.Exponent = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKeyDoc.SelectSingleNode("//RSAKeyValue/Exponent").InnerText);
            parameters.D = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKeyDoc.SelectSingleNode("//RSAKeyValue/D").InnerText);
            parameters.P = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKeyDoc.SelectSingleNode("//RSAKeyValue/P").InnerText);
            parameters.Q = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKeyDoc.SelectSingleNode("//RSAKeyValue/Q").InnerText);
            parameters.InverseQ = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKeyDoc.SelectSingleNode("//RSAKeyValue/InverseQ").InnerText);
            parameters.DP = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKeyDoc.SelectSingleNode("//RSAKeyValue/DP").InnerText);
            parameters.DQ = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKeyDoc.SelectSingleNode("//RSAKeyValue/DQ").InnerText);
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            rsaKey.ImportParameters(parameters);

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
            xmlDoc.LoadXml("<license><mode>Trial</mode><features><feature>All</feature></features></license>");

            Console.WriteLine("Started signing XML..");

            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
            signedXml.SigningKey = rsaKey;
            Reference reference = new Reference();
            reference.Uri = string.Empty;
            XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
            reference.AddTransform(env);
            signedXml.AddReference(reference);
            signedXml.ComputeSignature();
            XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
            xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
            {
                Async = false,
                Indent = true
            };
            stream.Position = 0;
            var xWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings);
            xmlDoc.WriteContentTo(xWriter);
            xWriter.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Completed creating and signing XML.." + "\n");

            // Removing BOM character
            string finalXmlContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
            string byteOrderMarkUTF8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
            if (finalXmlContent.StartsWith(byteOrderMarkUTF8))
            {
                finalXmlContent = finalXmlContent.Remove(0, byteOrderMarkUTF8.Length);
            }

            return finalXmlContent; 
        }

        private static Customer createCustomer(string customerName){
            Customer customer = new Customer(customerName);

            AsymmetricEncryptionService asymmetricEncryptionService = new AsymmetricEncryptionService();
            int keySizeBits = 2048;

            AsymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult = asymmetricEncryptionService.PersistNewAsymmetricKeyPair(keySizeBits);

            if (asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult.Success)
            {
                customerDictionary.Add(customer.GlobalId.ToString(), asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult.PublicPrivateKeyPairXml);

                Console.WriteLine("Public/Private Key Pair");
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customerDictionary) + "\n");
            }   
            else{
                Console.WriteLine(asymmetricKeyPairPersistenceResult.ExceptionMessage);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Customer is created successfully");

            return customer;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args){
            bool result = StartProcess();

            Console.WriteLine("RESULT");
            Console.WriteLine("-------");
            if (result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Doc signature is VALID");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Doc signature is INVALID");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The live/runnable version is at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uap80i

**Sample Output:**
[image: Sample Output]

**Note:** This example is for test purposes only for finding out whether the approach leads to success or not. Hence, the process is not identical but similar.

Comment: That worked as expected - the doc signature is valid according to the output.